# Trouble proving/disproving the existence of a particular derivative.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am having trouble with the following question:

**Quesiton:**

Define $f$ such that 
$$ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &\mbox{ if }x \ne 0 \\
0 &\mbox{ if } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Given this defintion, is the function $F(x) = \int_0^x f$ differentiable at $0$?

**Answer:** I believe the answer is no by the following reasoning. Please critique and correct.

We are trying to prove/disprove the existence of the limit
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(x + h) - F(x)}{h}$$
but this is equal to 
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(h)}{h}$$
Now, to determine whether this limit exists, we are only concerned with the value of $F$ at points $x \in (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$. We see that $F = \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for all such $x$, thus to show that $F$ is not differentiable at $0$ it suffices to demonstrate that 
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h}$$
does not exist. Now, in any deleted neighbourhood of $0$, $\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ infinitely many times. It follows that as $h \to 0$ we have $\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h}$ oscillating between $x$ arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small, and so the limit does not exist.

Comment: You're right in saying that the derivative of the integral doesn't exist but I don't see where you got that $F = \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.  I don't see how $F$ is even defined to begin with, are you sure it's integrable given those bounds?

Comment: @muzzlator Regarding the integrability, I'm taking the question from a book, so I would assume that it is integrable. Regarding $F = \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, you are right, that is incorrect. I overlooked that somehow, even after staring for quite a while.

Comment: Why do you think $\,F=\cos\frac{1}{x}\,$? Perhaps you meant $\,F'=\cos\frac{1}{x}\,$ ?...